# iOS - UITableView different cell types in different sections

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Two questions about `UITableView`:

**1)** Is it possible for a single `UITableView` to have two sections, one with dynamic cell type and the other one with static cell type?

**2)** When I added `UITableViewController` to the canvas, in Xcode attribute editor, I had options to specify the cell type *(dynamic/static)*. But I didn't see this option when I added a UITableView into a plain UIView. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**YES** it is possible for single `UITableView` with use of  **two sections**.

Here I put simple basic logic, I hope may be that is enough for you.  :)
Your `UITableView` has delegate method name is `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, in this method you can manage your section of `UITableView` such like put condition.

```
if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
  // here first section start with 0
  // and you can also manage row(s) of each section by put condition, such like

   if(indexPath.row == 0)
   {
     // here row 0 means row number 1 of particular section
   } 
   .
   .
   .

}
.
.
.
```

So you can easily manage your tableView by `section` and `row` 
In your case make each **row(s)** of **first section** is dynamic and each **row(s)** of **second section** is static.